# Qt5.7 Advertising and permissions

Tags: qt, bluetooth, permissions, bluetooth-lowenergy, root

Running this examples:

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html

as normal user I get the following error:

> qt.bluetooth.bluez: received advertising error

I don't want to run my application as root... what I need to freely access to the bluetooth management?
I've already added my user to the bluetooth group.

It's running on Debian Jessie Lite for RPi3.